# Passing parameters to a function when aggregating using pandas and numpy in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following code and data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
      'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      'B': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})
```

I want to calculate the 0.25 percentile for the column 'A' and the 0.75 percentile for the column 'B' using np.quantile. I try the following code:

```
(df.
 agg({'A' : lambda x: np.quantile(a=x, q=0.25),
      'B' : lambda x: np.quantile(a=x, q=0.75)}))
```

I obtain the following result:

```
     A     B
 0  1.0   6.0
 1  2.0   7.0
 2  3.0   8.0
 3  4.0   9.0
 4  5.0  10.0
```

However I was expecting the following result or something similar:

```
A    2.0
B    9.0
dtype: float64
```

The problem is that the lambda functions are computing the quantiles for each element of the series, rather than for the series as a whole.

My question is how I can obtain the expected result if a I want to use the agg function from pandas and the quantile function from numpy if I want to pass different parameters to a function using lambda functions.

I already read the posts [Python Pandas: Passing Multiple Functions to agg() with Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354329/python-pandas-passing-multiple-functions-to-agg-with-arguments) and [Specifying arguments to pandas aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43964439/specifying-arguments-to-pandas-aggregate-function) but they only work when the data is grouped and not when the data is not grouped.

Comment: I took the liberty to remove the paragraph on ChatGPT, we highly discourage its use here (the code it produces is often full of logical mistakes). It's not really on topic nor useful for future readers ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the `axis` parameter:

```
>>> df.agg({'A' : lambda x: np.quantile(a=x, q=0.25, axis=0),
            'B' : lambda x: np.quantile(a=x, q=0.75, axis=0)})

A    2.0
B    9.0
dtype: float64
```

You can also use a `partial` function:

```
from functools import partial

q25 = partial(np.quantile, q=0.25, axis=0)
q75 = partial(np.quantile, q=0.75, axis=0)

df.agg({'A': q25, 'B': q75})
```

Answer (score 2):

This works well with [`Series.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html):

```
df.agg({'A': lambda s: s.quantile(0.25),
        'B': lambda s: s.quantile(0.75)})
```

With [`numpy.quantile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html), you need to pass numpy arrays, not Series:

```
df.agg({'A' : lambda x: np.quantile(a=x.values, q=0.25),
        'B' : lambda x: np.quantile(a=x.values, q=0.75)})
```

Output:

```
A    2.0
B    9.0
dtype: float64
```